# How do you get the double-sided snapping arrow in Microsoft Visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio-2007

I'm using the Gane-Sarson shapes set in Microsoft Visio 2007 to create a data flow diagram. I am trying to find a double sided arrow, but the Data Flow shape in the Gane-Sarson set only shows one sided arrows.

When I search shapes for "arrow", I get a whole bunch, including the plain "arrow" shape, and when I resize it, it looks pretty ugly and it doesn't snap with the process shapes in my data flow diagram.  Is there another substitute I can use in this program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the "Universal Connector" which works great for me.

Comment: It would be great if you add more detail to your answer. It might help others who have the some question as you.

Comment: Using the "universal connector", on the 'Format Shape' pane, select the 'Begin Arrow type'. Use the same selection as the 'End Arrow type'.